# C++ Operator '+' overloading for builtin type and class both are on operand

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operands

```
#include "iostream"

class MyClass
{
public:
    float x, y, z;
    MyClass()
    {
        x = y = z = 0;
    }

    MyClass operator +(float a)
    {
        MyClass r = MyClass();
        r.x = this->x + a;
        r.y = this->y + a;
        r.z = this->z + a;
        return r;
    }
};

int Main()
{
    float xf = 0;
    MyClass vec = MyClass();
    vec.x = 10;
    MyClass other = vec + xf;
}
```

So everything is working fine for the code above. But I want to write like the code shown below:

```
MyClass other = xf + vec;
```

How to do that?

Basically, I want to add builtin types, lets say 'float' with my class type. Now that I can do that, as show in the first snap. But I do not want the directional behavior that "MyClass" type data has to be on the left side of '+' operator always.

**I want "MyClass" Type data on the right side of '+' operator while the builtin type('float' here) is on the left side.**

Doable?

Comment: *"Doable?"* Sure. Have you read the relevant part of your C++ book, or at least a relevant FAQ post like https://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/3002139 ? If so, what exactly is still unclear?

Comment: I want "MyClass" Type data on the right side of '+' operator while the builtin type('float' here) is on the left side. Like this:
MyClass other = xf + vec;